# Confluency of 3 indicators strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

can someone assist me with strategy build problem. I have strategy built in pine v4 and that works with 3 indicators.

Problem i have:
Long is set only when all 3 indicators are met at same time. That is fine but i want to have option where i cover situation of waiting One on Another indicator.
So indicator1 met condition true, waiting on others, once indicator 2 and Indicator3 are met true set Long. Of course by the time indicator3 is met conditions true, indicator1 and indicator2 should also be in met condition true.
Closing Long should be with same rule above and not only if all 3 at same time.

Or if it would be easier, creating indicator4 that will be set as true and plot some sign or whatever on chart, when all 3 indicators met true condition, or if all 3 false setting indicator4 as false and ploting different sign and then simply using indicator4 as strategy which maybe can give more flexibility later.

Again worth of mention that indicators/strategy are built in v4 so i would like to stick with this version for now since i am novice in all this.

thank in advance

I tried different variants of code but nothing changed behaviour of what i need. It is either all 3 at same time or not working at all so i cpuld not find proper option for this, tho i am not experienced in this so probably i am missing something.

what I tried:
defining all 3 indicators and then strategy but here, flag1 and flag3 are considered and only at same time, while flag2 is kept ignored for some very weird way.

```
periodK = input(title="Stoch %K Length", type=input.integer, defval=14, minval=1)
smoothK = input(title="Stoch %K Smoothing", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1)
periodD = input(title="Stoch %D Smoothing", type=input.integer, defval=5, minval=1)

k = sma(stoch(open, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = sma(k, periodD)

smaLength   = input(45, title = "SMA MA Period")


fastLength = input(8, title="Fast Length")
slowLength = input(17, title="Slow Length")
macdLength = input(9, title="Signal Line Length")

fastMA = ema(close, fastLength)
slowMA = ema(close, slowLength)
macd = fastMA - slowMA
macdSignal = ema(macd, macdLength)
macdHist = macd - macdSignal

plot(strategy.position_size)

flag1 = crossover(k, d)
flag2 = crossover(close, sma(close, smaLength))
flag3 = macdHist[0] > 0

longCond = false
if flag1 and not longCond
    longCond := true
if flag2 and longCond
    longCond := true
if flag3 and longCond
    strategy.entry("Long", true)
    longCond := false
```

aldo I tried adding line to have picture when to Long in nice way:

```
plotshape(longCond ? 1 : na, title="Long", style = shape.arrowup, location=location.abovebar, size=size.normal, color = color.green, text="Long")
```

but nothing is showing on chart :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Boolean’s. Set each to false and then when an indicators condition is met turn the Boolean for that indicator to true. Long condition is met when all three booleans are true.

Then reverse for your sell condition as each sell condition is met switch each Boolean back to false, sell when all 3 are false.

example:

```
flag1 = crossover(k, d)
flag1_bool = false
flag2 = crossover(close, sma(close, smaLength))
flag2_bool = false
flag3 = macdHist[0] > 0

if flag1
    flag1_bool := true
if flag2
    flag2_bool := true
if flag3 and flag1_bool == true and flag2_bool == true
    strategy.entry("Long", true)
```

You will need to define the conditions that reset the booleans back to false, other wise you will get a long condition on every flag3 signal.

Not sure what market you are using this on, but with SPY this generated more than 3 signals for me. The sell conditions I put in though were met almost immediately, but I don't know what your sell signal is. Also I did a quick convert to version 5

```
flag1 = ta.crossover(k, d)
flag1_bool = false
flag2 = ta.crossover(close, ta.sma(close, smaLength))
flag2_bool = false
flag3 = macdHist > 0

longCond = false

flag1_reset = ta.crossunder(k,d)
flag2_reset = ta.crossunder(close,ta.sma(close, smaLength))
flag3_reset = macdHist < 0

if flag1
    flag1_bool := true
if flag2 and flag1 == true
    flag2_bool := true
if flag3 and flag1_bool == true and flag2_bool == true
    longCond := true

if flag1_reset
    flag1_bool := false
if flag2_reset and flag1_reset == false
    flag2_bool := false
if flag3_reset and flag1_bool == false and flag2_bool == false
    longCond := false
```

Comment: Hm i am new to this so i am not sure what to do. So i am testing with simple indicators nefore i jump to complexity. So i defined macd, rsi and used Price croasingover sma20. Problem i have ia that acript is either waiting all of them at same time or waiting in particular order. Oh i defined them as separate flags but then strategy kept ignoring flag2 bit worked on 1 and 3 at same time lol. Going nuts. I updated original post with code I lastly tried. Can you give me example maybe pls?

Comment: I added code to my answer with an example of what you could do

Comment: i just updated code with your suggestion, did not change anything else, so did not reset conditions for back to false, wanted to see what will happen. but sadly nothing changed I still got just 2,3 trades across 10y span, and clearly signs of Strategy not entering long when it was supposed to do. not sure if problem in TV logic completely, or we are missing something. I even see 1 trade going in bad way, so Long when one of conditions are false (tho its 1 bar, so maybe different problem).

Comment: Not sure what market you are using this on, but with SPY this generated more than 3 signals for me. The sell conditions I put in though were met almost immediately, but I don't know what your sell signal is. Also I did a quick convert to version 5

Comment: i am checking on any stock example...currenly watching on ServiceNow. On weekly chart he is giving me only 2 entry points (for like 10 years) while clearly there are more, in last 2 months there is condition true (9 jan), one flag was true, then in next bars other 2 where true as well. Problem is that its not working in a successive way, logic as it seems is checking only if on same bar, which is not what I would like. So if today flag2 is met, tomorrow flag1 for example and next day flag3 we should get entry point, ofc everytime we check that other flag conditions are still true.